# Occurrences of each letter

Tags: java, string, search

this is the program that I have to write but I get this error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
50
```

Write a complete program using two arrays, upper and lower to keep the upper
And lower alphabet respectively.
Ask the user to enter string example:

> This is a test  from  Jupiter. Soon you will see who is from
>   Jupiter!!! May be Dr. D.

Your program should parse the string and keep track of number of alphabet. Both arrays are indexed from 0 to 25. The logical way to do this is to use upper[0] to
Count the number of ‘A’, and upper[1] to count number of ‘B’ and so on. Likewise
For the lower array.

Output should look like:

```
A: 0 a:2

B: 0 b:0
.
.
.
Z:0 z:0
```

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Letter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // this is get results
    char[] chars = userEnters();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Occurrences of each letter are:");
    PrintArray(countLow(chars), countUp(chars));
  }

  public static char[] userEnters() {

    String inputX = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter line of text:  ");
    char[] chars = inputX.toCharArray();

    return chars;
  }

  public static int[] countLow(char[] input) {
    int[] counts = new int[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      counts[input[i] - 'a']++;
    }
    return counts;
  }

  public static int[] countUp(char[] input2) {
    int[] countsUp = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < input2.length; i++) {
      countsUp[input2[i] - 'A']++;
    }
    return countsUp;
  }

  public static void PrintArray(int[] counts, int[] countsUp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {

      System.out.print(counts[i] + " " + (char) ('a' + i) + " ");
      System.out.print(countsUp[i] + " " + (char) ('A' + i) + "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: What do you think happens when you are in `countLow` and input[i] is an uppercase letter ?

Comment: You might want to filter out "invalid" characters such as `!`, ` ` and `.` as their code point is not within `a-z` or `A-Z`.

Comment: As others have said: before counting a lower case/upper case letter you must make sure it is actualy a lower case/upper case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope you don't mind I did refactor your code a bit.

Please have a look at this alterantive solution to your problem and then read the comments at the bottom of the answer.

```
   import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class LetterCounter {

    //Hash maps don't allow duplication. 
    //The letter will be the Key and the repetitions the value(Your goal!)
    private Map<Character, Integer> resultsMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LetterCounter letterCounter = new LetterCounter();
        letterCounter.fillMap();
        letterCounter.showMapContents();        
    }

    private void showMapContents() {
        for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : resultsMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("'" + entry.getKey() + "' - " + entry.getValue() + " times");
        }       
    }

    private void fillMap() {
        char[] userInputAsArray = getUserInputAsLetterArray();
        for (int currentLetter = 0; currentLetter < userInputAsArray.length; currentLetter++) {
            int count = getOccurences(userInputAsArray[currentLetter],userInputAsArray);
            resultsMap.put(userInputAsArray[currentLetter], count);
        }
    }

    private int getOccurences(int letter, char[] userInputAsArray) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < userInputAsArray.length; currentIndex++) {
            if(userInputAsArray[currentIndex] == letter)
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public char[] getUserInputAsLetterArray() {
        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter line of text:  ");
        char[] chars = userInput.toCharArray();
        return chars;
    }
}
```

- Whenever you want to do an exercise where you need to manipulate data, you should pick the best data structure for the job. In your case, I think the hash map could be interesting because it avoids duplicates and will do a big part of the job for you. Find a very good cheat sheet in this link: http://www.janeve.me/articles/which-java-collection-to-use
- I noticed that you used a lot static and that is not a very Object Oriented thing to do. As an alternative, when you want to just on the run do some quick examples like this one, you can just initialize the class inside itself.

I hope this was useful.

Comment: Thank you so much.It was a great answer. one more thing, how I can print all the letters and then say how many they are : for example a:0 A:0 .... z:2 Z:1

Comment: @Ali Ashtiani You're welcome. I am not sure what do you mean by how many they are? If you mean the total amount of letters, that is easy you just need to add up the value of each of the entries in the map.

Answer (score 7):

If you enter a character that is not a large cap, `countUp` will throw an exception and if you enter a character that is not a small cap, `countLow` will throw an exception.

Example: if you call `countLow` on a `A`, you calculate `'A' - 'a'` which returns `-32` and a negative index is not allowed.

You need to review your logic and call either countLow or countUp depending on the case of the letter and filter invalid characters out.
Or refactor the whole thing and use a `char[52]` for example where you hold both small and large caps.

Comment: OP also didn't cater to special characters. He uses ".", " " and "!" at least. Please update your answer with this info, another answer is unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider moving from arrays to a more complex and powerful data structure like `Map<Character,Integer>`.

With that data structure the code you need would look something like

```
public Map<Character,Integer> countOccurrencies(String inputString){
    Map<Character,Integer> occurrencies = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    for(Character c : inputString){
        if(occurrencies.containsKey(c)){
            occurrencies.put(c, occurrencies.containsKey(c) + 1);
        } else {
            occurrencies.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    return occurrencies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in java:

Here, `countOfOccurances("pppggggkkkkpgaaaa")` gives you count of occurrences of each       character from a String

```
   public static void countOfOccurances(String mainStr)
          {
            String temp = "";       
            for (int i = 0 ; i < mainStr.length();i++)
            {
            CharSequence ch = String.valueOf(mainStr.charAt(i));
            temp=mainStr.replace(ch, "");
            int count = (mainStr.length()-temp.length());
            System.out.println(ch+" = "+count);         
            mainStr = temp; 
            i = -1;
          }
          }
```

Output of method:

```
p = 4
g = 5
k = 4
a = 4
```